# Read Google Account Information with Apache Cordova Plugin

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using Apache Cordova for the build of a mobile Android application.
For the login mechanism I'd like to readout the google accounts which are set in the device, like getting the email and an authentification status.

Is this somehow possible through an cordova plugin or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

yes it is possible using the plugin 
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus
 in the success call back you can get the following things

```
 obj.email          // 'eddyverbruggen@gmail.com'
 obj.userId         // user id
 obj.displayName    // 'Eddy Verbruggen'
 obj.imageUrl       // 'http://link-to-my-profilepic.google.com'
 obj.idToken        // idToken that can be exchanged to verify user identity.
 obj.serverAuthCode // Auth code that can be exchanged for an access token and refresh token for offline access
```